# How to store asynchronous callback values in an variable?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, dapp-development

I am using ReactJS+Metamask for the web UI development. Since Metamask doesn't support synchronous approaches, I need to use callback functions to get my public variables. I found that with in the callback function, both `alert()` and `console.log()` can represent the correct variable. However, I want to store the value in an variable and display it in a list. But it seems that I cannot return this value or assign it to an existing variable.

Here is the code where `numIssuer` is a public variable in my contract. `num` will represent as undefined if I use `console.log(num)` after this:

```
var num = myContract.numIssuer(function(err,res){
    num = res;
});
```

or

```
var num;
myContract.numIssuer(function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

I am very new for front-end development. Is the problem with React or with web3?

Answer (score 1):

You probably does not understant the asynchronous nature of your call.  In the following example, `Line A` is executed **after** `Line B`.  Thats why in `Line B` you will see `undefined`:

```
var num;
myContract.numIssuer (function (err, res) {
  num = res; // Line A
});
console.log ("Num is: " + num); // Line B
```

You need to put received value into the list inside callback, not after the call like this:

```
myContract.numIssuer (function (err, res) {
  if (!err) displayInList (res);
});
```